# inicio de sesión según que rol

Tags: php

tengo 2 tablas =empleados, usuario.
Cuando inicie sesión el administrador quiero que tenga acceso a todo, pero cuando  inicie sesión un usuario que no lo sea, quiero que solo pueda ingresar datos y leer, nada de editar ni eliminar.

```
session_start();

 
if($_POST){
        include("./bd.php");

                
          $sentencia=$conexion->prepare("select *, count(*) as n_usuario
                                        from tbl_usuarios
                                        where usuario=:usuario and password=:password"); 



          $usuario=$_POST["usuario"]; 
          $password=$_POST["password"]; 

          $sentencia->bindParam(":usuario", $usuario);
          $sentencia->bindParam(":password", $password);

          $sentencia->execute();

         
          $registro=$sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);

          if($registro["n_usuario"]>0){

              $_SESSION['usuario']=$registro["usuario"];
              $_SESSION['logueado']=true;
              header("Location:index.php");

          }else {
              $mensaje="Error: usuario o contraseña incorrectos ";
          }
      ;


    };
```

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: En la BD puedes poner un campo de privilegio en el usuario y cuando se inicie sesión se carga ese valor como variable de sesión, luego en la programación permitirle o no acceder a secciones del sistema dependiendo del valor de esa variable. Si el sistema tendrá permisos modulares (distintos para cada usuario) entonces mejor crear una tabla de permisos y en los módulos php vas validando que puedan entrar los admin y los usuarios que tengan ese permiso.

Comment: a ok lo intentare .....muchas gracias